# Unable to open a file for writing which has write permisions

Tags: permissions, c

There is a regular file `file` in the `/tmp` directory with write permissions `-rw--w--w- 1 user1 user1 /tmp/file`

When I try to open this file as a user (I run the code after `su user2`) who is not the owner of the `file`, I get `Permission denied` error:

```
int fd = open("/tmp/file", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0622);
if (fd < 0)
{
    printf("%d, %s\n", fd, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

-1, Permission denied

And If I remove `O_CREAT` from the flags, the error disappears.

I don't understand this behavior, because the file has write permissions for everyone and there is no need to create it, since it already exists. Why does this fail with `O_CREAT`? Is this related to the sticky bit on `/tmp` ?  `drwxrwxrwt 25 root root /tmp/`

Distro is ubuntu, no selinux involved